# Saving file from post request using Flask only works locally

Tags: python, file, flask, openshift

**HMTL:**

```
<form action="/uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Python (Flask):**

```
@app.route('/uploadimage')
def saveImage():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        imfile = request.files['file']
        imfile.save('static/images/myimage.jpg')

        # also tried imfile.save('static/images/','myimage.jpg')
```

This seems to work fine on my local machine.

When I push my code to the remote repository on Openshift.com, it seems to cause problems.

I can't seem to find the error, I'm not getting any useful feedback from the logs.

Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: you should also sanitize the filename

Comment: look up `werkzeug.secure_filename()`

Answer (score 1):

Openshift have `data` and that `directory can be used for persistent storage`  | `filesystem`

You can get the directory using this environment variable `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`

And please save your file over there...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I'll test it and get back to you with the resultsd

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the difference between saving images, or saving html files. Why don't we have to use the env var for html, css or javascipt files?

Comment: I mean you are asking about saving your application code in data directory ?